# Android.widget,textView cannot be cast to android.widget,button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I keep getting a runtime error when launching my activity and it says android.widget.textview cannot be cast to android.widget.button?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewName"
        android:text="Level:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewClass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLevel"
        android:text="Class:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewClass"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewClass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Title:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewXP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:text="XP:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewXP"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Gold:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLineBreak"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewClass"
        android:text="________________________________________"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGoldValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewGold"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:text="Stats" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:text="Equipment" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="Inventory" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Shop" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewXP"
        android:text="Class Training" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Crafting" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLineBreak"
        android:text="HP:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStrTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewLineBreak"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewGoldValue"
        android:text="N/A"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewXPValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewGoldValue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewGoldValue"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLevelValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewClass"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewName"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewStrClass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewLineBreak"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewLevelValue"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewClass"
        android:text="Race:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextViewStrClass"
        android:text="10"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerMonsters"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnBattle"
        android:entries="@array/Monsters"
        android:prompt="@string/MonsterPrompt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinnerMonsters"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewXPValue"
        android:text="10"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBattle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinnerMonsters"
        android:text="Battle!" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewStrTitle"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerMonsters"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:text="/"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewXpNextLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewLevel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewLevel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnBattle"
        android:text="100"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewBattleResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerMonsters"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStrRace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewClass"
        android:text="l"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStrAlliance"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewStrTitle"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAlliance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Alliance:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewAlliance"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLineBreak"
        android:text="MP:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What is happening here? I've gone through it a few times and can't find anything

Edit:

```
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.intent_buttontests/com.example.intent_buttontests.PlayScreen}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.example.intent_buttontests.PlayScreen.onCreate(PlayScreen.java:110)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-17 18:28:51.485: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: You are probably doing `(Button) findViewById(R.id.actuallyATextView)` somewhere.

Comment: Need to see your Activity code that creates the views, but suspect you are attempting to cast a TextView to a Button, for example:  TextView textViewName = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textViewName); would cause such an error.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine... Please post the LogCat errors. Perhaps the error is in a different file?

Comment: I added the logcat. But i have no idea what is happening

Comment: Hi   this error is easy but can't understaning

Comment: Type Casting like button textview ,image

Comment: Button b=findviewbyid(R.id.btn);

Comment: textview    to include in xml file

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> I added the logcat. But i have no idea what is happening

This is the important information in your LogCat file:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
  at com.example.intent_buttontests.PlayScreen.onCreate(PlayScreen.java:110)
```

You read the error correctly, it is a `ClassCastException`. The lines below `Caused by...` tell you where the error was thrown, which is in `PlayScreen.onCreate()` on line 110. As best I can tell line 110 is:

```
Button btnBattle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBattle);
```

But this line is fine and the XML for `btnBattle` looks fine too...

I ran your Activity with your layout myself and didn't get any errors. Have you cleaned your project? Often this will remove these "phantom" errors.
(In Eclipse, **Project** -> **Clean...**)

---

I do have one suggestion, you have a lot of Buttons that do similar tasks. You can do the same actions with much less code if you use the XML `onClick` attribute. First create a method (call it `launchClick()`) in your Activity like so:

```
public void launchClick(View v) {
    Intent intent;

    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        intent = new Intent(PlayScreen.this, Inventory.class);
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        intent = new Intent(PlayScreen.this, Equipment.class);
        break;

    // etc, etc
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
};
```

And add the attribute `android:onClick` to every Button that you should have this behavior in `play_screen.xml`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:onClick="launchClick"
    android:text="Stats" />
```

Comment: I'm glad cleaning worked, but notice that I updated my answer. (I removed `implements OnClickListener` because that is not necessary.)

Comment: Always forget to clean the project :/!!! I searched and you saved me from asking a question!!! Thanks. (UPVOTED)

Comment: Thanks! Cleaning did the trick ! I would have never guessed it!
Co can we say its a bug in adt?

Comment: Cleaning the project especially after modifying stuff in your "res" folder seems to be a more valuable trick then I'd expect.

Comment: well said sam! it works after cleaning of the project. thanks

Answer (score 28):

**Project -> Clean** can help you.

Answer (score 4):

you are trying to cast `TextView` to `Button`.

for `TextView` do this :

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findviewById(R.id.your textviewid present in xml layout file);
```

for `Button` :

```
Button btn1 = (Button)findviewById(R.id.your buttonid present in xml layout file);
```

Comment: or do like this:-android.widget.Button myButton = (android.widget.Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);

Comment: This did the trick too! by the way, if you get environment error, I suggest you restart the IDE and try cleaning again after

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse go to Project > Clean, choose your project, and it's all... Your app will run normally...

Answer (score 1):

First make sure all `TextView` addressing the right `TextView` in your .java file..
Like this..

```
TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

Error like Android.widget,textView cannot be cast to android.widget,button raised because some time we referred `Button` instead of `TextView`.

If everything is ok then Clean your project and refresh.. It worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

I am using a RelativeLayout with 3 textViews and 2 buttons. I get the same bizarre error when I move the placement of the textViews using the graphical interface editor. If I set them back to where they originally were placed, the error goes away.

I can get rid of the error by:

1. Cut all the data from the offending XML file to the clipboard.
2. Save the project.
3. Clean the project (see error in the XML file)
4. Paste back the XML code and save
5. Clean
6. Run

This appears to be a bug since the XML code is legit, but does not get built at run time properly.

Hope it works for you.
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Answer (score 0):

Please attach your java code to find out where the problem is occuring. This problem comes when you are trying to convert the textview to button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Project > Clean

Or

2. change itemes Id's

it help :D

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. However, i decided to use only "View" without casting. It works perfectly. "setOnClickListener" works the same for our case.

e.g.
`View button = v.findViewById(button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(...)`

Answer (score 0):

In case the project clean does not work. The cause might be related to **use te same ID** on more than one item.

Make sure when assigning ID´s via layout or programatically, that are **not duplicated.**

I faced this issue while assinging low numbers as ID (probably not a best practice), as the ID's where colliding with RadioButton checked ID.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue, mine was with ImageView instead of TextView, and when I went back to check my activity, I discovered that I had already declared a variable as Button, and then I assigned the variable to findViewById(R.id.ivrest), where ivRest refers to an ImageView, so just make sure if you declare a variable with a particular type, when reassigning the variable it's should be of the same type