# Android apps cant even run.Logcat show "android.widget.text view cannot be cast to android.widget.Button."

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new in android application here..And my apps cant event run,and i just dont know why..The logcat there keep showing this

> android.widget.text view cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

here is my code in mainactivity.java

```
package com.loginandregister;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // setting default screen to login.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button registerScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

    // Listening to register new account link
    registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    Button loginScreen = (Button)  findViewById (R.id.link_to_login);

    // Listening to register new account link
    loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

login.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#ffffff">

       <!--  Header Starts-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

        <!-- Logo Start-->
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
        <!-- Logo Ends -->
</LinearLayout>
<!--  Header Ends -->

       <!-- Footer Start -->
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dip"
    android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</LinearLayout>
<!-- Footer Ends -->

        <!-- Login Form -->
        <LinearLayout

          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dip"
          android:layout_below="@id/header">
          <!--  Email Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Email"/>
          <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:singleLine="true" />

          <!--  Password Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Password"/>

          <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:password="true"/>
          <!-- Login button -->
          <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Login"/>
          <!-- Link to Registration Screen -->

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/link_to_register"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
              android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:text="New to Plot Out?Register here"
              android:textColor="#0b84aa"
              android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
<!-- Login Form Ends -->

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#fff">

        <!--  Header  Starts-->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip">
                <!-- Logo Start-->
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
                <!-- Logo Ends -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--  Header Ends -->
        <!-- Footer Start -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dip"
                android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Footer Ends -->

        <!-- Registration Form -->
        <!-- Registration Form Ends -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Full Name"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_fullname"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Register New Account" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/link_to_login"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Already has account! Login here"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/images" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Bring Me Out"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:text="Plot Out"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="134dp"
        android:text="Forgot Your Password?"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/link_to_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/link_to_register"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/link_to_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/link_to_login"
        android:text="Register" />

   >

</RelativeLayout>
```

So all expect here,anybody can help me on this???
Thank in advance

Comment: You can't cast a TextView to a Button. Either registerScreen or loginScreen is actually a TextView (maybe both, can't tell without xml).

Comment: If you have no TextView in your xml layout file, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465551/android-widget-textview-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-button

Comment: wait..i upload my xml here

Comment: just added my login.xml and register.xml here..

Comment: You are referencing the wrong id. For example, reference btnLogin (a Button) instead of link_to_login (which is a TextView)

Comment: is it i need to change in login.xml and register.xml??

Comment: tq very much sir..i get it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
Button registerScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
```

`Button loginScreen = (Button)  findViewById (R.id.btnRegister);`

instead of

```
Button registerScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);
`Button loginScreen = (Button)  findViewById (R.id.link_to_login);`
```

you are casting the ID's of textViews instead of buttons.
OR
Change the ID name of buttons in main.xml ..

Comment: sir,i add the code just like you said..but still the same..is it something wrong in my xml??

Comment: ok just try to change the id name's of buttons to something else ...in main.xml

Comment: wow..is work bro..thank you very much..after change the id in main.xml to btnRegister and btnLogin..all is work..tq very much for your help..

Comment: @ken I am glad I could be of help no problem ... please accept it as an answer so that others could also get help... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your local variable `loginScreen` is of type `Button`, but you are calling `findViewById()` with the id of a `TextView`. Use `R.id.btnRegister` if you really want to hook the button before the text field.

Comment: i add it to this >Button registerScreen = (Button)  findViewById (R.id.btnRegister); and this >Button loginScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

Comment: You need to provide more detail than just "it cannot work".  Are you seeing exception, are you not receiving callbacks?  It's also helpful if you provide updated code and logcat output.