# App crashes when I am trying to switch between tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash, speech-recognition, onclicklistener

I'm trying to add a Button that can prompt speech input in my android app and return the speech into a text form to be shown through a TextView. But once I add the below code into my fragment, my app crashes once I try to switch my view to that specific tab containing the fragment and speech button.

Code for speech button (note that my microphonebutton is within the onCreateView for my fragment and not a seperate onClickListener method) and my app only crashes when the following code are added... :-

```
microphonebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

                if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)  {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Your device does not support speech input !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (resultCode) {
            case 10:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    textView.setText(result.get(0));

                }
                break;
        }

    }
```

Logcat that shows once the app crashes :-

```
10-01 23:39:37.875 27828-27828/project.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: project.myapplication, PID: 27828
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at project.myapplication.Translator.onCreateView(Translator.java:101)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1984)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:668)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:630)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:611)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2191)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1164)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1157)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1127)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1426)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1536)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says that you're casting **AppCompatImageButton to Button.**
Check your code where you bind the button with xml.

```
Button button = findViewById(your_button_id);
```

Make sure it's casted correctly.
Check out this link for more information - [ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12467263/4981655)