# My android app keeps stopping. I have checked the logcat and its a classcastexception

Tags: android

I got an error ;
**java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView.
at com.FoodOrdering.adapters.HomeVerAdapter$ViewHolder.(HomeVerAdapter.java:61)
at com.FoodOrdering.adapters.HomeVerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HomeVerAdapter.java:33)
at com.FoodOrdering.adapters.HomeVerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HomeVerAdapter.java:18)**

Can you help me identify the error I have posted my HomeVerAdapter below?

```
package com.FoodOrdering.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.FoodOrdering.R;
import com.FoodOrdering.models.HomeVerModel;

import java.util.List;

public class HomeVerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeVerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  Context context;
  List<HomeVerModel> list;

   public HomeVerAdapter(Context context, List<HomeVerModel> list) {
       this.context = context;
       this.list = list;
   }



   @NonNull
   @Override
   public HomeVerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_vertical_item, parent, false));
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeVerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

       holder.imageView.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImage());
       holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());

   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return list.size();
   }

   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

       ImageView imageView;
       TextView name, timing, rating, price;

       public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ver_img);
           name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
           timing= itemView.findViewById(R.id.timing);
           rating= itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
           price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
       }
   }
}
```

Home_Vertical_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="9dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ver_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/dinner"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/product_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".15"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rating"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ratingbar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
                android:text="@string/_5_0"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rating"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rating"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/_10_00_23_00"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_access_time_24"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/min_45"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/timing"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rating"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"/>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: `AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`

Comment: see here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465551/android-widget-textview-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-button , basically the same thing

Comment: Thank you. From the above code I can't see where I got the code wrong between the Imageview and Textview

Comment: post your layout as well, `home_vertical_item`

Comment: a_local_nobody is correct.  You've defined name, timing, rating and price as "TextView", but your layout defines one of them as "ImageView", not "TextView".  Check your layout.  In particular, it appears line 61 is "price".

Comment: I have added home_vertical_item

Comment: Thanks. It has worked . I had defined rating as ImageView in layout and in Adapter I defined it as TextView

Comment: @Biran Kirui: +1 for following up - thank you.  Normally, this kind of question would be "closed/typo".  But please consider posting your "answer": summarize the problem and solution, then "accept" it.  To help others who might encounter a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @paulsm4: okay sure.